# What does 's(c)' stand for in the following query?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to know the role of this method 's()' in the following postgresql query :

```
SELECT name, employee_id
FROM users u
,LATERAL (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users u2 WHERE u.employee_id = u2.employee_id) AS s(c)
WHERE c > 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`s` is the subquery alias. `c` is an alias for name of the column in the subquery.

Let's take a simpler example

```
select s.c from (SELECT 1) AS s(c);
 c
---
 1
```

which can also be written as

```
select s.c from (SELECT 1 as c) AS s;
 c
---
 1
```